# jQuery all list items in menu is set to active instead of just the selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the structure of my menu. I have attached the jQuery code below. The way this works is that when I click on Home Page, its parent element which is the list item has a class that is set to active.

At the moment, When I am at the Home Page, its list item has an active class. However, the list-items for Account Codes and Branches also have an active class set on it. How can I make sure that only my Home Page is affected?

Also, how can I change my jQuery code to work with this menu format where there is a new list within a list?

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="navigation-menu">
    <li><a href="/" class="nav-link"><i class="far fa-square"></i><span>Home Page</span></a></li>
    <li class="menu-header">Administrator Mode</li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown"><i class="fas fa-fire"></i><span>Configuration</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/Configuration/Account Codes" class="nav-link">Account Codes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Configuration/Branches" class="nav-link">Branches</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var current = location.pathname;
        $("#navigation-menu a").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
                console.log($this);
                $this.parent().addClass('active');
                console.log("matched");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I've edited the question now with normal HTML. Thanks!

Comment: This is a logic problem more than anything else. The two offending anchors have the character `'/'` in them, so all of them match. Rather than asking if the `href` contains the current path, ask if the `href` *ends with* the current path.

Comment: Oh thats a really good idea. But how accurate does it get? Is it something like Contains?

Comment: Also, how can I make it so that my <li class="nav-item dropdown"> is also active when an item inside that list is selected?

Answer (score 0):

## Dropdown Layout

The most effective HTML layout pattern for dropdown menus is to alternate between `<ul>`/`<ol>` and `<li>`:

> ```
> <ul>
>    <li class='dropdown'>
>      <a href="#/">Dropdown</a>
>      <ul class='menu' style='display:none'>
>       <li>Item</li>
>       <li class='dropdown'>
>         <a href='#/'>Dropdown</a>
>         <ul class='menu' style='display:none'>
>           <li>Item</li>
>           <li>Item</li>
>         </ul>
>       </li>
>     </ul>
>   </li>
> </ul>
> ```

Also, if you want the menus to be initially closed, add the following inline style:

> ```
> <ul class='menu' style='display:none'>
> ```

The `<a>`nchors have default behavior that is hard to override when using a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation. Try toggling the `.active` class on `.has-dropdown` children tags.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
/*
Delegate click event to each .has-dropdown
Toggle .active class on that particular .has-dropdown children tags
Get next .dropdown-menu and toggle it up/down and toggle .active
*/
$('.has-dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: tomato
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/css/foundation.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul id="navigation-menu" class="sidebar-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#/" class="nav-link">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i><span> Home Page</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-header">
    <a href="#/" class="nav-link has-dropdown">
      <i class="fas fa-tools"></i><span> Administration</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav-item dropdown-menu" style='display:none'>
      <li>
        <a href="#/" class="nav-link has-dropdown">
          <i class="fas fa-lock"></i><span> Security</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style='display:none'>
          <li>
            <a href="#/" class="nav-link">
              <span> Account Codes</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#/" class="nav-link">
              <span> Branches</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/" class="nav-link has-dropdown">
          <i class="fas fa-cog"></i><span> Configuration
        </span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style='display:none'>
          <li>
            <a href="#/" class="nav-link"><span> Layout</span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#/" class="nav-link"><span> Assets</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```